# Remove a wordpress add_filter function from plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a plugin that is creating a custom template via add_filter:

```
// Create a template view for the new CPT
add_filter('single_template', [$this, 'setTemplateAVATAR'] );

public function setTemplateAVATAR ($template) {
    global $post;
    if ( $post->post_type == 'AVATAR' ) {
        return self::generateCustomTemplate('avatar.php');
    }
    return $template;
}
```

I need to disable this somehow via functions file so that that instead of using it's custom template is uses the template defined in my theme. How would I go about disabling this filter from running?

Comment: If I understand you correctly , you may use remove_filter()

Comment: @KenLee how would that be structured in a way that only applied to that one instance? 

I've tried: 
`remove_filter( 'single_template', 'setTemplateAVATAR' );`

Answer (score 0):

You would take the `add_filter()` hook and use `remove_filter()` and try the hook name and function name parameters the same.

```
remove_filter('single_template', 'setTemplateAVATAR' );
```